# Change css of content inside span inside li

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, html

I'm trying to have the style set of read/unread messages in my listview in jQuery Mobile.

```
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" id="#messageList" style="padding-top:10%;">

                    <li data-icon="false">
                        <a href="#" onclick="messageClick()">
                         <p>
                            <span style="float:left;clear:left;font-weight: bold;text-decoration:underline;color:blue;white-space:pre-wrap; width:30ex">Some unread text</span>
                            <span style="float:right;font-weight: bold;">08/02/13</span>   
                         </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    .....
                    </ul>
```

The inside `messageClick()` I have :

```
function messageClick(){    
    $(this).findclosest("span").css("font-weight","normal");
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You seem to be confusing [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/). There is no `.findclosest` function. In this case, you want `.find()` to search descendants, `closest()` searches ancestors.

Answer (score 4):

`findclosest` is not a function.  Look at your javascript console and I'm sure you're getting an error.  Also `this` is likely not set to the element, but rather the window since you're calling it in global scope.  What you likely want is something more like: `<a href="#" class="messageClick">`

and

```
$('#messagelist').on('click','a.messageClick', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('span').first().css(...);
    return false;
}
```

Note that I went up to the parent to then find the first span.  I did this because a block element `p` cannot exist inside `a` so different browsers might treat that differently.  I'd highly suggest using classes instead of inline styles and targeting based on those classes instead of some random DOM hierarchy.  Your code could use some serious cleanup!

Comment: My code code definitely use some cleanup. I'm not that good at CSS, just beginner. And as for your answer, it makes sense, but doesn't work. Maybe I'm messing up things elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

What is `findclosest()` it does not exist in jQuery documentation. If you want to access the first span under the `<li`> something like this should work:

```
function messageClick(){    
    $(this).find("p > span:first").css("font-weight","normal");
}
```

If you want to change both span you can remove the `:first` from the selector, and even go with just `$(this).find("span")` if you don't have multiple span.

Answer (score 2):

You want `find()` not `findclosest()` - which doesn't exist:

```
function messageClick(){    
    $(this).find("span").css("font-weight","normal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile dont work well with onclick="... or occhange="... events, they are in conflict with jQM page event triggering.

You should bind click event manually liek this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#messageList li a', function(){   
        $(this).find("span:first").css("font-weight","normal");
    });    
});
```

And here's a working sjFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Speu2/

Comment: I think it has something to do with jQM only. Your fiddle works great, but the same stuff doesn't work in my project. Wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use .find as I don't think that .findclosest exists (.closest does though but is not for that)